# passing anonymous function as parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript code:

```
   EventsManager.prototype.hideContainer = function()
   {
     var that = this;

     var index = that.getNextUnreadEventIndex();
     if(index !== -1)
     {
         EventsManager.animateHideLeft(function() //<--- passing a function as parameter to another function
         {
             var unreadEvent = that.eventsList.splice(index,1)[0];
             unreadEvent.isEventOnFocus = true;

             that.eventsList.push(unreadEvent);
             that.displayLastEvent();
         });  
     }
   }
```

Here is the EventsManager.animateHideLeft() function's code:

```
EventsManager.animateHideLeft = function(callback)
{
   var p = document.getElementById("eventsContainer");
   var width = parseFloat(p.style.width);

   if(!width || width === "NaN") width = 200;

   if(width <= 10)
   {
      clearTimeout(fr);
      alert(typeof callback); //<-- this shows "undefined"
      callback();
   }
   else
   {
      width = width - 10;

      p.style.width = width + "px";

      fr = setTimeout(function()
      {
          EventsManager.animateHideLeft();
      }, 50);
  }
};
```

Unfortunately the function animateHideLeft does not work as expected. When i test typeof callback it alerts "undefined".

How can i fix this kind of mess so i get the expected result?

Comment: In addition to question asked, take a good look at `if(!width || width === "NaN") width = 200;`. Make sure it does what you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you just need to pass `callback` through the call in `setTimeout`.

```
fr = setTimeout(function()
{
    EventsManager.animateHideLeft(callback);
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing callback at other place

```
 fr = setTimeout(function()
      {
          EventsManager.animateHideLeft(function(){
                ////
        });
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you call it wrongly from the `setTimeout()`:

```
EventsManager.animateHideLeft();   // No callback!
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `setTimeout` you don't pass the `callback` on to the next invocation:

```
      EventsManager.animateHideLeft();
```

Change it to

```
      EventsManager.animateHideLeft(callback);
```

However, it's not a bad idea to test against `typeof callback == "function"` since sometimes you don't want/need a callback function and the `callback();` invocation would lead to an exception then.

Btw, you should not need to `clearTimeout(fr);` (unless you plan to invoke the function multiple times during an animation).